# Spring Controller/Component Implements Serializable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, serialization

In a recent Web based Java project, I have come across various places where I have seen a Spring based **Controller/Component** implementing `Serializable`.

I am curious, as to why a **Controller/Component** should have to implement `Serializable`?

I think it is wrong practice to do so and searching so far for any scenario to implement `Serializable` has not yielded anything. I think it violates MVC principle and is unconventional. You would want to keep *Domain/Business* Objects separate from **Controllers/Components**.

I would like to correct this bad practice in the code base but just wanted to ensure I have a reason to do so.

Any explanation/scenario illustrating this case will be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds wriong to me. Are you able to post the code?

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for controllers to be `Serializable`. They're stateless and just mediate between the model and the view. The same could be said for other stateless components. There's no benefit in making them `Serializable`.

Stateful model objects, however, are often `Serializable` because they're sometimes placed in `HttpSession`. App servers require objects in session to be `Serializable` for replication and persistence purposes.

Answer (score 0):

A specific use case that requires the Controller classes to implement Serializable is when working with [spring session](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5).

Spring session will externalize the session - I use spring session with JDBC to co-ordinate the session between containers. When you have a Session Scoped Controller spring session will serialize that state to and from the database using a byte[] column.